# show that the function $f(z)=Arg(iz)$ is discontinuous at the point $z_0=i$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I tried to solve it by taking two different paths like the way showing that $f(z)= Arg(z)$ is discontinuous at any point in the negative real axis, but the two paths I have taken gave me the same answer.. any other ideas please !!

Comment: This is going to depend on your definition of $\operatorname{Arg}$. Basically, you're being tasked with showing that $g(z) = \operatorname{Arg}(z)$ is discontinuous at $-1$.

Comment: yes that was the question .. Now do you have any idea how to prove this ??

Comment: If you know that $\operatorname{Arg}$ is discontinuous on the negative real axis, then you can use that _directly_ to show that $f$ is discontinuous. No need to use paths or anything this time. $f$ is just the function $\operatorname{Arg}$ turned $90^\circ$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, basically we're trying to show that $Arg(iz)$ is discontinuous at the point $i$ on the complex plane. Define a function $q$ given by:

$$q(t) = Arg(e^{i(\frac{1}{2}\pi + t)}), \quad t \in (- 
\frac{3\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$$

Observe that $e^{i(\frac{1}{2}\pi + t)}$ is the form of any point on the circle centered at $0$ with a radius of $1$.

Also, notice that

$$\lim_{t \to - 
\frac{3\pi}{2}^+} Arg(e^{i(\frac{1}{2}\pi + t)}) = -\pi$$

and

$$\lim_{t \to \frac{\pi}{2}^{-}} Arg(e^{i(\frac{1}{2}\pi + t)}) = \pi$$

What we have shown is that if you approach the point $i$ on the complex plane counter-clockwise around the circle parametrized by $e^{i(\frac{1}{2}\pi + t})$, our function outputs $\pi$. However, if on the same circle we approach $i$ clockwise instead, our function outputs $-\pi$. Since we obtain completely different outputs from $Arg(iz)$ as $z \to i$ (i.e. $\pi$ and $-\pi$) along the circle parametrized by $e^{i(\frac{1}{2}\pi + t)}$, we have to conclude that

$$\lim_{z \to i} Arg(iz)$$
does not exist. So, $Arg(iz)$ can't be continuous at $i$.